# purrr::map equivalent to dplyr::do

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

Reading https://twitter.com/hadleywickham/status/719542847045636096 I understand that the `purrr` approach should basically replace `do`.

Hence, I was wondering how I would use `purrr` to do this:

```
library(dplyr)
d <- data_frame(n = 1:3)
d %>% rowwise() %>% do(data_frame(x = seq_len(.$n))) %>% ungroup()
# # tibble [6 x 1]
#       x
# * <int>
# 1     1
# 2     1
# 3     2
# 4     1
# 5     2
# 6     3
```

The closest I could get was something like:

```
library(purrrr)
d %>% mutate(x = map(n, seq_len))
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#       n         x
#   <int>    <list>
# 1     1 <int [1]>
# 2     2 <int [2]>
# 3     3 <int [3]>
```

`map_int` would not work. So what is the `purrrr` way of doing it?

Comment: I think you need `tidyr::unnest` at the end of the chain.  I don't know if that's the "purrr way", but it is a way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)
d %>% by_row(~data_frame(x = seq_len(.$n))) %>% unnest()
```

`by_row` applies a function to each row, storing the result in nested tibbles.
`unnest` is then used to remove the nesting and to concatenate the tibbles.

Comment: Side note: `by_row` [seems to have been moved](https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/blob/master/NEWS.md) to the package [`purrrlyr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/purrrlyr/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Using `pmap()` removes the need for nesting and unnesting.

```
library(tidyverse)
d %>% pmap_df(~data_frame(x = seq_len(.)))
```